# If $y$ is continuously differentiable and $y' \leq 1-y^2$ then $|y| \leq 1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $y(t)$ is continuously differentiable for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y' \leq 1-y^2$ then $|y| \leq 1$.

I'm trying to prove this, and it feels like a question that can be proven with the comparison theorem for differential equations.

So taking $x' = 1-x^2$ we immediately get that the functions $x(t)=1$ and $x(t)=-1$ solve this equation, which seems indeed strongly related to what we need to prove.

Now, from Ricatti, we can take a general solution $x=1+u$, and solve it.
I derived $$x=\frac{2ce^{2t}+1}{2ce^{2t}-1}$$
Not sure how to continue from here. Even if I get a solution this only compares one side of $y$, and I want to compare both of them. Also, there isn't any initial conditions which I understand is necessary for the comparison theorem.

I also believe that the solution uniqueness theorem can be applied here in some way but I'm not sure about it.

Thanks!